# What is the proper word to describe the co-occurrence of an increase of one thing and an decrease of another thing in popularity

Tags: word-usage

I am trying to disambiguate some concepts, and I wonder if there is such a word (better as familiar as possible to the general public) to describe the situation in the title. It can be a more than one words, 2 is ok, too.

The two things are related. For example, they can be apple and orange, both are fruits. The scenario could be apple is more popular in populationA than in populationB, while orange is more popular in populationB than in population A.

Also, is there a more scientific word for popularity?

Comment: How about negatively correlated? When A goes up, B goes down, or vice versa, statistically speaking.

Comment: What if I am more interested in populationB and I try to emphasize the difference in populationB compared to populationA, I am trying to saying something like populationB-specific fruit popularity shift. But it's so awkward... Do you have any suggestion, please?

Comment: That's different from the title. If you interested in differences in population preferences, I'm not sure where you can go with it. Different populations may have different preferences. For example, the Japanese prefer fish, whereas Americans prefer beef (assuming that's true). I'd call that something like different population preferences.

Comment: That's cool insight, and I called that differential preference. But it goes a bit too far. What if say 20% of Americans like beef and 80% like fish while 40% of Japanese like beef and 60% like fish. In such a case, both Americans and Japaneses prefer fish over beef, but there is obviously a difference. Is there a word?

Comment: From your question, I thought you were talking about shifts over time.  But apparently not. // Maybe: fish is proportionately more popular in Japan than in the U.S.  Meaning that fish has a larger share in the preference frequencies in Japan.  See https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/proportionately.  I think you should read some basic statistics and that will enable you to pick up the way statisticians phrase these things.

Comment: Inverse implies 2 items only, right? What if there is a third item, e.g. orange?

Comment: Those two things have an inverse relationship. (http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/inverse_1)